# python cluster or group binary data in 2 dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis

I am trying to identify areas of minerals/gas within Starcraft 2 maps for my bot.  The image below shows a plot of a 2 dimensional array I have in which 1's denote a mineral or gas patch.

Eyeballing it you can see there are 4 clusters which I would like to identify.

I have tried using:

```
from scipy.ndimage import measurements
lw, num = measurements.label(map)
```

(map) is a 64,64 array with ones where there is a mineral/gas patch.

This finds 21 clusters because within the 4 clusters, there is some whitespace.

Also, I do not know how many clusters I am looking for when I get an array.  I was looking at Connected-component labeling, but I could not see a way to see as long as 1s are say 3 or 4 positional elements away, they can be considered connected.  I have only seen 4 or 8-connected methods.

Any ideas how I should tackle this problem?

[image: map showing minerals/gas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clusters seem clearly separated, so just grow them a bit to fuse their parts. For example you could use `scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation`:

```
from scipy.ndimage import measurements, morphology
import numpy as np

# create mock data
data = """

  1111 1                     1
       1                    1
        1              11111



 111111 111
           1
           1

"""

data = np.array(data.split('\n'))
data = data.view('U1').reshape(len(data), -1) == '1'
# blow it up a bit
data = np.kron(data, np.ones((2, 2), dtype=int))


# "algorithm" starts here
grow = morphology.binary_dilation(data, structure=np.ones((5, 5), dtype=int)
lbl, npatches = measurements.label(grow)
lbl[data==0] = 0
# end of algorithm


# show
res = '\n'.join(lbl.astype('U1').view(f"U{lbl.shape[1]}").ravel()).replace('0', ' ')
print(res)
```

Output:

```
        11111111  11                                          22
        11111111  11                                          22
                  11                                        22  
                  11                                        22  
                    11                            22222222      
                    11                            22222222      






      3333333333    333333                                      
      3333333333    333333                                      
                          33                                    
                          33                                    
                          33  3333                              
                          33  3333
```

If it doesn't directly work on your actual data, try a different structuring element or simply dilating multiplr times.

Comment: This worked great. Thanks. I forgot to put in the second part of my task to the original post. Not sure if I should create another post or not, but thought I'd try asking.  I also need to find where to place an object at optimum distance from each of these clusters.  For example, how could I find the nearest point to each of the clusters that is at least 4 units (Euclidean distance) from each element within the cluster?  ie the point cannot be within 4 units of distance of any part of the cluster.

Comment: @CraigHamilton I think that's distinct enough for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial to cluster with single-link hierarchical clustering, or DBSCAN. Just use a distance threshold that is small enough to join near minerals, and separate far minerals. Probably 5 cells works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I will learn about this approach as well.

Answer (score -2):

This is actually an entire class of problems, [clustering algorithms](https://home.deib.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/).

I would recommend starting with an iterative k-means style approach such as the one [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html). You could run it for sizes 2 - n (or however many clusters you think you will find) then use the P-values to gauge how confident the clusters are. (ie, P value should be very high/unsure when running k-means with 2 clusters when there are clearly 3 clusters on the map, where as they should be low/sure if you run a k-means with 3 clusters)

Good luck!